# Complexity of extracting a coefficient of a polynomial in multiple variables

Tags: time-complexity, polynomials

I'm looking for efficient algorithms for problems of the following type:

Let's say we have the variables $x_1,...,x_n$.

Over these variables, we are given a function $p_1\cdot ... \cdot p_m$, consisting of $m$ polynomials $p_1,...,p_m$, each of which is a multivariate polynomial itself, of the form
$$
\sum_{\matrix{0\le i_1\le k\\...\\0\le i_n\le k} }a_{i_1,...,i_n} x_1^{i_1}\cdots x_n^{i_n}
$$
, where $k$ is the highest degree appearing in any of the polynomials $p_1,...,p_m$.

How do we efficiently extract a coefficient from $p_1\cdot ... \cdot p_m$?

---

Efficient in this case is relative, as the problem is  [#P-complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sharp-P-completeness_of_01-permanent) via [MacMahon's Master Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permanent_(mathematics)#MacMahon%27s_Master_Theorem) (it reduces the problem of calculating the permanent to extracting a coefficient of a function as given above).

Nevertheless it's a popular function, implemented in many CAS-systems, and with many applications in e.g. combinatorics.

I'm interested in both efficient algorithms (with complexity bounds) as well as theoretical complexity bounds.

Comment: When you wrote “in #P”, did you actually mean “#P-hard”?

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Yes, that's right, more precisely it's #P-complete